# A weird relation for exponential function, is it really correct?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis

> We written if $$f(x_1 + x_2) = f(x_1)f(x_2)$$ means that $f(x) =
>  a^x$ and this is a characteristic property of the exponential
> functions.

This to me seems really weird, I am sure that there exist more functions for which this is true. Did the professor make a mistake here?

Comment: Hmmm, do you mean ${f(x_1 + x_2) = f(x_1)f(x_2)}$?

Comment: If he wrote it exactly like this, it is surely a typo... As it is, it's just false.

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose Yes I did a typo, but the question is still the same

Comment: @PierreCarre Yes he written $\cdot$ instead of plus, but the question is still the same

Comment: Why are you sure there are more functions satisfying this property? The result is actually correct.

Comment: @PierreCarre I don't know it just seems weird to me, but if it is correct, than that answers my question

Comment: If you take the logarithm on both sides then you get the [Cauchy functional equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/423492), which, under some mild conditions, has only linear functions as solutions.

Comment: @PierreCarre: If you don't require (e.g.) continuity then there are other solutions as well.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, you are correct.